# document.querySelectorAll("span + a") didn't work?

Tags: getelementbyid, selectors-api

I have a HTML like this.

```html
<span class="vm-video-side-notification-text-item">
    <a href="/video_copynotice?v=4XrAMcXy0co" class=" yt-uix-sessionlink " data-url="/video_copynotice?v=4XrAMcXy0co" data-sessionlink="ei=DTr_V7jrJM2luAKd1JSgCQ">Includes copyrighted content</a>
</span>
```

I use

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("span + a");

alert(x.length);
```

the alert is "0"... I don't know why.
I see the w3school says

> element+element
>   div + p
>   Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

so I try span + a. Can anyone correct my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating elements with tags.

While the start tag of the `a` is directly after the start tag of the `span` indeed, the `a` **element** is inside the `span` **element**.

So, in order for your example to work, you can either

1. change the query selector to `"span > a"` for "any `a` directly inside a `span`"

   ```
   var x = document.querySelectorAll("span > a");

   alert(x.length);
   ```
2. or change the html to have the `a` element after the `span` element

   ```
   <span class="vm-video-side-notification-text-item">
   </span>
   <a href="/video_copynotice?v=4XrAMcXy0co" class=" yt-uix-sessionlink " data-url="/video_copynotice?v=4XrAMcXy0co" data-sessionlink="ei=DTr_V7jrJM2luAKd1JSgCQ">Includes copyrighted content</a>
   ```

(... but not both!)